# How to solve the link error caused by broken lines？

Tags: ubuntu, neovim, coc.nvim

[image]

- I can't open a link completely. How can I solve it?
- My_enviroment: neovim v0.6.1,coc.nvim,ubuntu22.04LTS
  My mother tongue is not English, please understand the subtle grammatical errors.Thanks you！

I hope I can open the link completely.

Answer (score 0):

`C-ww` to move your cursor to floating window and put on link, `gx` to open.